# Object missing form final render

Tags: rendering

[image]
[image]

The chocolate icing is missing from the final rendering, in 3D Viewpoint, it is showing. I have tried using W key under Edit mode, but the special menu is not showing up, but switches selection tools. Thanks for your time. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the "render" checkbox is active in the object's visibility settings;

[image]

Comment: It is selected, and it is still not showing in the render. :D

Comment: What version of Blender are you using?

Comment: That's not it, check the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Properties* panel > *Particles* > *Render*, make sure that the *Show Emitter* option is enabled.

[image]

Comment: I never knew that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty actually that is mentioned at some point in the donut tutorial (this is from the BlenderGuru donut video tutorial series, right?)

Comment: I am just now watching half of his donut tutorials done in 2.8. I'll be sure to check out emitter in his series. Thanks for mentioning. :)

Comment: This is working! Last night I could not sleep by thinking about this problem. Thank you so much @moonboots. I started learning blender from that donut tutorial too. It covered a lot of stuff after I am digging into it more. Thank you again!!!!